# how to convert the query result data to json format in kusto query language

Tags: kql

I'm working on a logic app which will create a bug I have to display description in the work item like below:

```
{
    "Description":
    {
        "Title":"", 
        "Validation step":"",
        "OperationActivityId:":"",
        "Environment detailsLink":"",
        "Please click here":"",
        "ErrorMessage":""
    }
}
```

I'm Querying all above mentioned fields as result of query from Kusto(KQL) and getting all the required fields but I don't know how to convert it to make it Json.
Can anyone help me on this..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, please accept the answer if it helps (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)). If you're missing some info, please let me know what's missing, and I'll elaborate.

Answer (score 8):

Here you go:

```
PackedRecordlet MyTable = datatable(Category:string, Value:long) [
   "A", 1,
   "A", 3,
   "A", 5,
   "B", 1,
   "B", 2
];
MyTable
| extend PackedRecord = pack_all()
| summarize Result = make_list(PackedRecord)
```

This will output everything in a nice json:

```
[
  {
    "Category": "A",
    "Value": 1
  },
  {
    "Category": "A",
    "Value": 3
  },
  {
    "Category": "A",
    "Value": 5
  },
  {
    "Category": "B",
    "Value": 1
  },
  {
    "Category": "B",
    "Value": 2
  }
]
```

Explanation

- [`pack_all()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packallfunction) puts all the data from the columns of a record into a JSON
- [`summarize make_list(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makelist-aggfunction) takes all these JSONs, and creates a list (array) from them

Comment: Slavik N, Interestingly this works up to a certain result set size.  Beyond that size the query takes a very long time and ends up returning nothing.  In my test case when I tried 1600 columns and 28,000 rows the query completed (I had increased max row and memory size for the query), but the result set was empty.  I was using results.primaryResults[0]._rows[0] to get the JavaScript object which worked with smaller numbers of columns and rows.  When it become that large, that simply returned an empty array.